# С чего начать изучение svg?

Tags: css, svg

Нужно за очень короткий срок изучить анимацию с помощью svg. подскажите, пожалуйста  с чего нужно начинать?
Может быть есть какие-то готовые библиотеки, которые облегчают работу с svg анимацией?

Comment: основы svg => https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial  отсюда начните

Comment: svg animation => https://habr.com/ru/post/450924/

Comment: тоже не плохо объясняют об анимации svg => https://css-live.ru/articles/rukovodstvo-po-svg-animaciyam-smil.html

Comment: @MaximLensky сппасибо

Comment: раз вопрос задан здесь, то начинать изучение можно с чтения [описания метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/svg/info)